# How to suppress information on integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-10

In Visual Studio Code v1.40 on Windows 10, the integrated terminal window always shows the information below.

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476] (c) 2019 Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\Python Projects>

Is there a setting to suppress this so that the terminal window only shows output and error messages?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107170/hiding-the-full-file-path-in-a-powershell-command-prompt-in-vscode/52107556#52107556 to modify the path shown at the command prompt.

Comment: @mark Thanks for the response, but I am not trying to modify the path. I'm trying to hide the copyright line and hide  the path and just show output from the code and error messages in the terminal window, if it is possible.

Comment: Well, the second line is the command prompt - you can't completely hide that, other than by shortening it.