# Modifying information displayed in terminal (VSCode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have an aesthetic problem with my VSCode terminal. On this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5hor.png) you can see, that whenever I try to run my code, terminal also displays information about the directory folder. It's annoying and completely useless to me... Is there a way to modify terminal settings, so that this shit is not displayed? After running the code I only want to see the result - in this case words "hellow world".
In some guides I've seen people having it that way, however I can't do it.
System: MacOs; Python 3.X

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you are just referring to your command prompt.  Hopefully someone responds with macOS-specific info.  If it helps, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107170/hiding-the-full-file-path-in-a-powershell-command-prompt-in-vscode/52107556#52107556 the commands might be the ssame.