# How do I stop Visual Studio Code from displaying my file directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Hi I'm trying to learn Python and this is the first time I use Visual Studio Code so I'm a complete beginner. 
In the lessons that I'm following, the output of the code is visible in *debug console*, like the screenshot below:
[image: target output]

In my installed version of Visual Studio Code (Win 7 32bits) I get all the output in the *terminal* section and it also shows my file directory, which I find distracting.

[image]

I'd like to set up Visual Studio Code so I get roughly the same results as the first picture, without my file directory being printed out once for every line of code... Is that possible?

Comment: For the Powershell prompt part of your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107170/hiding-the-full-file-path-in-a-powershell-command-prompt-in-vscode/52107556#52107556

Comment: If that is the extent of your question, then this is a duplicate of that link I cited.  Otherwise, I suppose it is two questions in one and should be split.