# Can I remove the location from my terminal in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I've searched extensively but can't find a solution.

After every single output I get this location data:

```
PS C:\Users\pretend\ADrive\Documents\GitHub\Code>
```

Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Comment: Not sure how much you know about terminal, but that's indicating your current directory in the terminal session. This is not a feature of vscode, but a feature of your terminal shell. If you're unaware of the command line, I highly recommend https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/ . The reason it's putting you in that directory is because that's where your vscode project is open.

Comment: You have to change the `prompt` of the shell. `PS` in the prompt suggests you use a `Power Shell` terminal. Do a search.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107556/836330 right on point.  Step by step.  In fact your question is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you all so much. Yes, I'm very new. I did search for the answer but as evidenced by my lack of understanding, I didn't really know where to look. Thank you again!