# configure display vs code terminal path directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, path, configure

I was `using` the `Visual Studio Code` as an `IDE` to code and then I met a problem.

On the `terminal`, the path, the working directory was displayed too long.

Like this

[image]

I want to change the `PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Github\onboard-something\onboard-java-mysql>`

to something shorter like `>`

How can I do that ?

Thank you guys very much.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107556/836330 (`Hiding the full file path in a PowerShell command prompt in VSCode`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function as specified below:

function prompt( ) {">"}

Answer (score 0):

Just to be more detailed,

Open up **VSCode** -> **New Terminal** -> Close the PowerShell if poped up -> Open a new cmd window -> now just paste **"prompt $g"**.

[image]

[image]

Note: It will only work on CMD and not Powershell, for that you might have to use profiles.